# How can I make deletion of an object in a collection cascade in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I have these two objects that are part of an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
}
```

I added this mapping to problem:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Problem)
   .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProblemId);
```

Now when I remove one of the questions from the Problem object and save it removes the question from the problem table but the question is left as an orphan in the question table.

Is there a way that I can make it remove the question also?

For reference here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Problem] (
    [ProblemId]       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Answer]          NVARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Problem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProblemId] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProblemId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [Title]            NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    [Explanation]      NVARCHAR (4000)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionProblem] FOREIGN KEY ([ProblemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Problem] ([ProblemId]),
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Question_ProblemId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Question]([ProblemId] ASC);
GO
```

Comment: I don't understand how the question is left in the table as an orphan when the foreign key is non nullable.

Comment: I agree with @user2697817. Your problem doesn't make sense

Comment: @Anne Have you thought about doing your Edits (Add/Modify) via a SProc and calling that SProc from your DBContext?